# About isomorphism of Extension groups between Category $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathcal{O}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

In the paper: **[Kostant modules in blocks of category $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604336.pdf)**

In section 8.2 (p.22), I use the notation in Humphrey's Category $\mathcal{O}$ book.

Then the passage said the following:
``The general formula follows from the following isomorphism (which is proved
using a **Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence** argument as in [ES1, Chap. 15])

$
\text{Ext}^i
_{\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}}(M_I(w_Iy\cdot\mu), L(w_Iw\cdot\mu)) \cong\text{Ext}^i
_{\mathcal{O}}(M(w_Iy\cdot\mu), L(w_Iw\cdot\mu)),
$

where $M(w_Iy\cdot\mu)$ is the ordinary Verma module of highest weight $w_Iy\cdot\mu$ in the block $\mathcal{O}_\mu$ of
ordinary category $\mathcal{O}$."

Note that $M_I(w_Iy\cdot\mu)$ is the parabolic Verma module defined in Humphrey's book Ch. 9. And $L(\lambda)$ is the unique simple subquotient of both $M_I(\lambda)$ and $M(\lambda)$.

Does anyone know how to use **Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence** argument to show the isomorphism for any $y,w\in {}^SW^J$ and any anti-dominant integral weight $\mu\in\mathfrak{h}^*$?